# Translations API

Tags: windows-phone

Are there any translation APIs that you could use to download and work with within the windows phone framework?   This is without having to call to an outside service via the web.

Comment: If you want to translate text built into your app (as opposed to user-contributed content), perhaps you could add various localizations to your app. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637522(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Not at this point**.

***Why?*** Due to their nature, direct translation on the device would require *a lot* of effort, not because you're just translating word-for-word, but also have to consider language semantics and grammar. You could, of course, roll your own solution, but at that point your marginal benefit will be reduced to zero compared to using an existing web API.